# Alternate title case in jQuery

Tags: jquery, uppercase, lowercase

I want a string to randomly alternate uppercase and lowercase letters.

To do this I grab the content of class "post__title" into a string, explode that string into an array of letters. Then loop that array and randomly assign either 0 or 1 to each letter. If the value is 1, the letter should be transformed to uppercase, if the value is 0, the letter should be transformed to lower case. This then has to be reapplied to "post__title" replacing the old content.

I'm quite inexperienced, but so far I have the following, which results in the console error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined". I cannot seem to figure out how to get it to work.

```
$(window).load(function() {
var z;
var title = $('.post__title').text().split("");
for (i = 0; i < title.length; ++i) {
    z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
    if (z==1) {
        title[i].this.value.toUpperCase();
    }
    else {
        title[i].this.value.toLowerCase();
    } 
};
$.map(title, function(val,index) {
    var str = index + ":" + val;
    return str;
}).join(", ");
$(".post__title").text(str);
});
```

Comment: you dont need `this.value`, just use `title[i].toUpperCase();`

Comment: What's with `(1 - 0 + 1)`?  Why not just `2`?

Comment: Klaas who are you talking to? Use `@someone` to let the user know you replied

Comment: @stackErr Ah sorry, I messed my comment up. Thanks for your help!

Comment: you should accept one of the answers below if this question is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will work:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var z;
    var title = $('.post__title').text();
    var str = "";
    for (i = 0; i < title.length; ++i) {
        z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
        if (z==1)
            str += title[i].toUpperCase(); //put value in str, no need for .this.value
        else
            str += title[i].toLowerCase();
    };

    $(".post__title").html(str);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(window).load(function() {
    var z;
    var title = $('.post__title').text().split("");
    for (i = 0; i < title.length; ++i) {
        z = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 - 0 + 1)) + 0;
        if (z==1) {
            title[i].toUpperCase();
        }
        else {
            title[i].toLowerCase();
        } 
    $.map(title, function(val,index) {
        var str = index + ":" + val;
        return str;
    }).join(", ");
    $(".post__title").text(str);
    });
```

You were using `title[i].this.value.toUpperCase();`. that is incorrect since `title[i]`already has the reference to the letter. Just call `toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()` on `title[i]`.